# Avoiding JSpinner to take letters

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a `jSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` like this:

```
spinnerModelFix = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 65535, 1);
JSpinner fixedValueSpinner = new JSpinner(spinnerModelFix);
```

I just want to show Integers in the spinner, so that if the user insert letters they aren't shown.

I thought I should `extends SpinnerNumberModel` and `override` the `fireStateChanged()` method...

But I'm not sure what I need to do in that method.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- yes is possible and workaround is quite simple,
- there are two ways how to do it, have to derive `JTextField` or `JFormattedTextField` from `JSpinner`,
- then to add

  a) `DocumentListener`

  b) `DocumentFilter`

I think that usage of [DocumentFilter is easiest for code workaround, better, maybe safer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779203/714968)

Comment: @Max author of this idea is King of JTextComponents

Comment: This works, but when the displayed value is higher than 1000, arrows to increase or decrease the value doesn't work anymore... You know what could be the problem?

Comment: aaach in the SpinnerNimberModel:-), there are four values, and two of them are min a max value :-)

Comment: I changed to `new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 65535, 1)` but it don't solve the problem...

Answer (score 2):

You can try [setAllowsInvalid(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultFormatter.html#setAllowsInvalid%28boolean%29) on spinner's formatter. For example:

```
SpinnerNumberModel spinnerModelFix = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 65535, 1);
JSpinner fixedValueSpinner = new JSpinner(spinnerModelFix);
JFormattedTextField textField = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) fixedValueSpinner
        .getEditor()).getTextField();
((NumberFormatter) textField.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid(false);
```

Comment: This seems to work more or less, but it don't let me deleted all the numbers if I want. It needs to have at least one digit...

Comment: @amp `DocumentFilter` suggested by @mKorbel may be more suitable for your case.