# how to increase the size of jspinner arrows as per touch screen requirements on desktop

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jspinner, uimanager

Hi Can anybody help me  to
how to increase the size of jspinner arrows as per touch screen requirements on desktop

Comment: I think you can't directly modify that size without changing L&F properties.

Answer (score 2):

change the size of JButton in spinner components like this:

```
        spn = new JSpinner();   
        spn.getComponent(0).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
```

JSpinner has three component. two JButton and one JTextField.

1. the 1st component is nextButton
2. the 2nd component is previousButton
3. the 3rd component is NumberEditor

Answer (score 1):

> help me to how to increase the size of jspinner arrows as per touch screen requirements on desktop

- even is possible to change

  a) `PreferredSize` for `Buttons` (in `API` limited by `Icons size 8x8`, have to override too)

  b) relayout `Buttons` in JSpinner one on the `LEFT (or SOUTH)` and 2nd or `RIGHT (or NORTH)`
- but for `JSpinner` I wouldn't going this way

---

- create `JTextField` / `JFormattedTextField` with `DocumentListener`, implement there all limits to the `DocumentFilter` ([by default for JSpinner is there the same requirements too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826561/714968))
- put there two `JButtons` (by using `JButton#setXxxIcon` to set own `Icon`), for `inc / des creasing` value
- for `Date` / `Calendar` use proper `JCalendar` or `JDatePicker`

Answer (score 1):

You might try one of these:

- See if a *large* [size variant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html) is available for your chosen Look & Feel.
- Change the `Spinner.arrowButtonSize` property using the `UIManager.put()` method.

Comment: Please elaborate the second option. Property arrowButtonSize can't be found.

Comment: The key is `"Spinner.arrowButtonSize"`, for [example](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/11/all_ui_defaults_names_common_java_look_and_feels_windows_mac_os_x_and_linux), but not all L&Fs support it.