# How to Auto Calculate input numeric values of Text Field in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have problem with Text Field Auto Calculation in JAVA using Netbeans 7.2

My Question is if I will input numeric values in Text Field i-e (admission fee, monthly fee, transport fee etc) for auto addition and then input numeric values in Text Field i-e (dues) to auto subtract from the above auto addition before clicking submit Button to insert the total values in database so how i will get result of those numeric values in Text Field (Total) before clicking submit Button.

**Please check snapshot:**

[image]

**My Source code:**

```
try
         {

            String insrt = "Insert into fee (admission, monthly, transport, dues, total) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insrt);

            pstmt.setString(1, adm_fee.getText());
            pstmt.setString(2, mnth_fee.getText());
            pstmt.setString(3, trnsprt_fee.getText());
            pstmt.setString(4, dues_fee.getText());
            pstmt.setString(5, total_fee.getText());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record successfully inserted");
        }

        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "auto calculate"? Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: p.s. Typically you shouldn't store calculated data in a database. Most DBMS's contain functionality to do these kinds of calculations upon request. This is preferred because the original data can easily be modified without changing the "calculated" data.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Code-Guru .... i want to Auto calculate sum of all Text Field numeric values then show sum value in Text Field name Total...also i want if i put dues values which auto subtract from sum of all value in the Text Field name Total....please check my snapshot image for better understand my question...

Comment: Again, what does "auto calculate" mean? Using the word again doesn't explain what it means.

Comment: I understand that you want to get the numeric values and do some kind of calculation. However, I'm unclear if you want to do this calculation *as the user enters the data* or *when the user clicks Submit*. Perhaps I'm just getting hung up on your wording. "Auto calculate" doesn't mean anything in my vocabulary.

Comment: @Code-Guru see my example, I think OP means as the data is entered into textfields he wants to display the results *on the fly* in another textfield i.e so a button click for *calculate* is not needed to be clicked

Comment: And is there a reason that you are storing numeric data in your database as text? This seems like a Bad Idea (TM). Similarly, storing calculated data isn't very good, either. I can imagine scenarios where the calculated data can get out of sync with the data it is calculated from.

Comment: @Code-Guru yes "Auto calculate" doesn't mean anything but i add this word for understand my question what i want.....also thank you so much for great help using " Text " instead of integer so i will change it too....once again thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest use a `DocumentFilter` this will allow us to kill 2 birds with 1 stone.

1) we need to filter what is inputted to `JTextField`s to make sure our calculation wont go wrong

2) We need to update the total on the fly i.e as more digits are added/removed.

Here is an example I made which uses `DocumentFilter` and as you will see the *Total* field will be updated each time a new digit is entered/added to the `JTextField`(s) (also it wont allow alphabetic characters etc only digits):

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class DocumentFilterOnTheFlyCalculation {

    public DocumentFilterOnTheFlyCalculation() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DocumentFilterOnTheFlyCalculation();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Add:");
        final JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField();

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Add:");
        final JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField();

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Subtract:");
        final JTextField jtf3 = new JTextField();

        JLabel totalLabel = new JLabel("Total:");
        final JTextField totalField = new JTextField("0");
        totalField.setEditable(false);

        DocumentFilter df = new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int i, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {

                if (isDigit(string)) {
                    super.insertString(fb, i, string, as);
                    calcAndSetTotal();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1) throws BadLocationException {
                super.remove(fb, i, i1);
                calcAndSetTotal();
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {
                if (isDigit(string)) {
                    super.replace(fb, i, i1, string, as);
                    calcAndSetTotal();

                }
            }

            private boolean isDigit(String string) {
                for (int n = 0; n < string.length(); n++) {
                    char c = string.charAt(n);//get a single character of the string
                    //System.out.println(c);
                    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {//if its an alphabetic character or white space
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            void calcAndSetTotal() {
                int sum = 0;

                if (!jtf1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(jtf1.getText());//we must add this
                }
                if (!jtf2.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(jtf2.getText());//we must add this
                }
                if (!jtf3.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    sum -= Integer.parseInt(jtf3.getText());//we must subtract this
                }

                totalField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        };

        ((AbstractDocument) (jtf1.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);
        ((AbstractDocument) (jtf2.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);
        ((AbstractDocument) (jtf3.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);

        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(jtf1);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(jtf2);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.add(jtf3);
        frame.add(totalLabel);
        frame.add(totalField);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply sir @David Kroukamp
sir actually i am beginner with JAVA and i am not familiar with DocumentFilter, InputVerifier and DocumentListener....i am confuse to how to use with my source code so please can you little help with source code how to do it ?

Comment: Thanks for reply sir @David Kroukamp .... yes sir i looking your update and i am going to try it to do with my source code....if i will fail then again i will contact you but sorry don't mind for disturbance....thank you much for great help.

Comment: dear sir @David Kroukamp .... thank you so much for great help and its fine working me....

Comment: dear sir @David Kroukamp i need some more help ASAP about above your source code of auto calculation. how i will put restrictions so user wont enter value more then 99999 in all invoice TextFileds.thanks

Comment: @SilentHeart see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305921/detecting-jtextfield-deselect-event/14305952#14305952) answer. I would suggest you use `DocumentFilter` as you already using it and it can be done with minimal changes to code

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need an update for each keystroke, this [alternate approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513) uses both a `FocusListener` and a `PropertyChangeListener` to `update()` the total as changes accrue.

[image]

Comment: +1 for `FocusListener`. I was going to suggest it and make a example but though the every key stroke better

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Thank you; it's slightly simpler to use `JFormattedTextField` for numeric input, but your `DocumentFilter` may be more flexible.

Comment: I intiailly suggested that and a `InputVerifier` (dropped verifier for same reason as `FocusListener`) and `JFormattedTextField` actually doesnt seem fit for variable lenght masks, i.e I put a mask to accept 6 digits, if I only enter 2 digits and click next `JFormattedTextfield` the input would disappear as it didnt match the mask (of 6 digits) I see you can create a variable length mask, but even more work :P..

Comment: @David Kroukamp never to confuse the user [i.e I put a mask to accept 6 digits, if I only enter 2 digits and click next](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582656/714968), then to use JSpinner instead

Comment: @David Kroukamp please can I rollback my idiotic comment about JSpinner, this is the same road to the hell and usage of JFormattedTextField, [JSpinner with SpinnerNumberModel required DocumentFilter too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9779203/714968), otherwise is possible to input non_numeric chars too, sorry winner is plain JTextField with DocumentListener & DocumentFilter

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KlNS.jpg)You can use MouseEntered event to auto display computed value in jtextfield as shown in the code

```
private void TxtnetpayMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
  DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
  double totalgrosssalary = Double.parseDouble(Txttotalgrosspay.getText());
  double totaldeduct = Double.parseDouble(Txttotaldeduction.getText());     

    netpay = totalgrosssalary - totaldeduct; 
    String netpayy = String.valueOf(numberFormat.format(netpay));

    Txtnetpay.setText(netpayy);
}
```