# Allow only digits (without any limit in number of digits) in a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, jformattedtextfield, documentfilter

How to allow only digits (without any limit in number of digits) in a `JFormattedTextField`? I mean I don't want to check to see what has been entered in my `JFormattedTextField`, itself doesn't allow any input except digits.

Comment: any input???, without decimal separator and negative sing ??? or not

Comment: only digits from 0 to 9 and nothing else !

Comment: have look at DocumentFilter with Pattern, nothing else !

Comment: I don't know how to use it...

Comment: you can to use this [DocumentFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9779203/714968), could be valid for all kinds o [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)