# How to define a formatted text field in Swing so that the format restrictions are applied as you type?

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I need such a numeric text field on JFrame  that

1. restricts the input by a number with two digits after decimal
   point
2. lays out the number separating  every three digits i.e. 1
   234 567,89.
3. the number is displayed in correct format right away
   during typing

I tried using JFormattedTextField:

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    NumberFormatter numFormater = new NumberFormatter(nf);
    field1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(numFormater);
```

However, format restricitions apply only when focus leaves the component, which is a problem. I want user to be able to type only digits and delimeter in the field, and a space delimeter be placed right after each 3-d digit is entered in the field.

I can do this in C# just by specifing properties of the field. What is a clean way to do this in Swing? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

- one of ways is usage of `InternationalFormatter` which is additional `Formatter` for `Number or DecimalFormatter`
- every restriction in `JFormattedTextField` has side effects for users input, e.g. `Caret`, `Selection`, etc.
- proper of ways could be usage of combinations `DocumentFilter` with `DocumentListener` added to `JFormattedTextField` with plain `Number or DecimalFormatter`, without any restrictions, all workaround will be set in both `DocumentFilter`(designated for changes inside `Document`) with `DocumentListener`(outside of Document)

for example mentioned `InternationalFormatter`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.InternationalFormatter;

public class DocumentListenerAdapter {

    public DocumentListenerAdapter() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AbstractTextField Test");
        final JFormattedTextField textField1 = new JFormattedTextField(new Float(10.01));
        textField1.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {
            @Override
            public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
                NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
                format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
                formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
                formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
                formatter.setMaximum(1000.00);
                return formatter;
            }
        });
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        final JFormattedTextField textField2 = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormat);
        textField2.setValue(new Float(10.01));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DocumentListenerAdapter();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

for example [JSpinner (editor is JFormattedTextField) with very simple DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779203/714968)

Comment: Quite a complete answer +1 :)

Comment: @mKorbel there is a strange effect in this solution: after delimeter is added after 4-th, 7-th,... digits, the caret happens to be misplaced. If one types 123123123, the result of the input is 123 232 311,00 (Locale: ru). Unfortunately this is very inconvenient, and I suppose there is a bug in implementation somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a KeyListener to the field and reformatting whenever a key is typed?

Comment: what is a proper way to invoke reformatting? Switching focus between components doesn't seem clean, and there is a problem of caret misplacement.